# Как правильно запушить объект в такой массив объектов?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой что не знаю как правильно на реакте можно запушить объект в массив объектов с использованием деструктуризации

```
 const [newObj, setNewObj] = useState(
    {id: 1, title: 'firstItem', tasks: [{title: 'asdasd'}]}
  );
```

Как будет правильней всего запушить в tasks еще один объект с титлом? Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: В стейте должен быть массив.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
setNewObj((pr) => ({...pr, tasks: [...pr.tasks, { title: '1' }]}))
```